# Can I go for PhD ( in person ) and master's (online) simultaneously in different subjects?

Tags: phd, research-process, career-path, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I have just started my PhD program in Nanoscience in the United States as an International Student. I have a master's degree in Physics and have decent skills in Python too. I have practiced several machine learning projects (YouTube taught) with Tensorflow. I am studying "Hands on machine learning..." by Geron Aurelien and have some other books collected (recommendations). I wish to have a college degree in AI/ML too so that I can blend both my skills (core science and computation) for future research and exploration to become a research scientist. Am I allowed to enroll in an online degree  provided by any other university? If Yes, what are the recommended institutions for such a course????

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already in a doctoral program you should ask someone at your university about this. Having just started you may not yet have a dissertation advisor, but may have an academic advisor. They would be good for advice. Otherwise, the department head can advise.

Personally, I'd advise against it, even if you are very good and it is allowed. The MS program could jeopardize appropriate progress is the doctoral program, especially if comprehensive exams are part of the process as is typical in the US.

The other reason I advise against it is that there is no particular reason to do these simultaneously. Once you are "certified" with a doctoral degree you gain some freedom to study other things, perhaps with the guidance of a degree program or on your own.

Don't make the perfect the enemy of the good.

And, of course, either program could have a veto on your enrollment in another program, thinking that it would leave you overextended and wanting to spread resources to other qualified candidates. While you might make it work, there is (IMO) no essential need to over-complicate your life and studies.

Comment: Seems likely that they could minor in data science, particularly if there are projects needing it in the department. (In my PhD program one had to have an out-of-department ‘minor’, with 3 or more  grad classes and a member of one’s committee out of it.)